# Видимость меток в яндекс картах в зависимости от масштаба

Tags: яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

Прошу помочь в решении задачи: на сайте созданном на вордпресс будет яндекс карта. На карте необходимо разместить метки, но таким образом чтобы они были видны только при большом (максимальном) приближении к месту их расположения. Т. Е. При открытии карты должна открываться карта всего мира без меток вообще, в том числе не должно быть и групповых меток. И только при приближении к какому-нть городу начинают отображаться метки со ссылками